# Can "buildBase" point to directory outside current project in SBT?

Tags: sbt

Let's say I have an existing (old) codebase and I'd like the least-invasive way of demoing how to compile it with SBT. I'd like to accomplish it in such a way that the file-structure of the root directory containing the codebase is completely untouched. This means that `project/Build.scala` will need to be outside of the actual project. Also, keep in mind that since the existing project has a non-standard layout and uses a lot on unmanaged dependencies there's quite a bit of configuration that needs to be done (like setting unmanagedSourceDirectories, unmanagedJars, etc.)

Consider the example layout below:

```
/opt/workspace
        |
        +- existing-codebase
        | |
        | +- module1
        | | |
        | | +- src
        | |
        | +- module2
        |   |
        |   +- src
        |
        +-  sbt-demo-build
          |
          +- project
            |
            +- Build.scala
```

Also, let's say I have the following environmental variable set:

```
CODE_HOME=/opt/workspace/existing-codebase
```

So, what needs to go into `Build.scala` to indicated that the build base (`buildBase`?) is `/opt/workspace/existing-codebase` rather than `/opt/workspace/sbt-demo-build`

I tried setting `baseDirectory` key, but SBT just fails with:

> java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed: Directory /opt/workspace/existing-codebase/module1 is not contained in build root /opt/workspace/sbt-demo-build

This is `DemoBuild` I use in the project:

```
import java.nio.file.{Paths, Files}
import sbt._
import Keys._

object DemoBuild extends Build {
  val codeHome = Paths.get(sys.env("CODE_HOME")).toAbsolutePath.
                       toRealPath().normalize().toFile
  ...
}
```

The best analogy I can think of is Ant's `basedir` attribute in the `project` element - does this concept not exist in SBT (or is it just not exposed properly)?

#### Update:

After digging around for a bit I found something called `xsbti.AppConfiguration` which seems to correspond to a Setting called `sbt.Keys.appConfiguration`. I attempted to override using:

```
  appConfiguration ~= { cfg =>
    new AppConfiguration {
      def arguments(): Array[String] = cfg.arguments()
      def baseDirectory(): File = codeHome
      def provider(): AppProvider = cfg.provider()
    }
  }
```

But got the same AssertionError. Then, I found some [official docs](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Detailed-Topics/Launcher.html) that might help, so I'll be looking into those as the next step

Answer (score 4):

### OPTION 1

Use `/opt/workspace` as the project directory for your SBT project. Use it as you meant to have used `/opt/workspace/sbt-demo-build`.

### OPTION 2

Use the following build definition in `build.sbt` that defines two SBT modules outside the current project directory.

```
lazy val root = project in file(".") aggregate (module1, module2)

lazy val module1 = ProjectRef(file("../existing-codebase/module1"), "module1")

lazy val module2 = ProjectRef(file("../existing-codebase/module2"), "module2")
```

It assumes `module1` and `module2` are SBT projects and `root` project aggregates them so running a command in `root` [will also run it on the aggregated projects](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Getting-Started/Multi-Project.html#dependencies).

### OPTION 3

When on Unix, symlink the projects with `ln -s` that are outside the build root.

```
jacek:~/sandbox/so/andrey-workspace/sbt-demo-build
$ ln -s ../existing-codebase/module1 .
jacek:~/sandbox/so/andrey-workspace/sbt-demo-build
$ ln -s ../existing-codebase/module2 .
jacek:~/sandbox/so/andrey-workspace/sbt-demo-build
$ tree
.
├── build.sbt
├── module1 -> ../existing-codebase/module1
└── module2 -> ../existing-codebase/module2

2 directories, 1 file
```

Use the following `build.sbt` in which the projects are defined.

```
jacek:~/sandbox/so/andrey-workspace/sbt-demo-build
$ cat build.sbt
lazy val root = project in file(".") aggregate (module1, module2)

lazy val module1 = project

lazy val module2 = project
```

In SBT console, `projects`, `project` and `run` worked perfectly:

```
jacek:~/sandbox/so/andrey-workspace/sbt-demo-build
$ sbt
[info] Loading global plugins from /Users/jacek/.sbt/0.13/plugins
[info] Set current project to root (in build file:/Users/jacek/sandbox/so/andrey-workspace/sbt-demo-build/)
[root]> projects
[info] In file:/Users/jacek/sandbox/so/andrey-workspace/sbt-demo-build/
[info]     module1
[info]     module2
[info]   * root
[root]> module1/run
[info] Running Hello
Hello from module1
[success] Total time: 1 s, completed Jan 11, 2014 9:40:03 PM
[root]> project module1
[info] Set current project to module1 (in build file:/Users/jacek/sandbox/so/andrey-workspace/sbt-demo-build/)
[module1]> run
[info] Running Hello
Hello from module1
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed Jan 11, 2014 9:40:20 PM
[module1]> project root
[info] Set current project to root (in build file:/Users/jacek/sandbox/so/andrey-workspace/sbt-demo-build/)
[root]> show baseDirectory
[info] module1/*:baseDirectory
[info]  /Users/jacek/sandbox/so/andrey-workspace/sbt-demo-build/module1
[info] module2/*:baseDirectory
[info]  /Users/jacek/sandbox/so/andrey-workspace/sbt-demo-build/module2
[info] root/*:baseDirectory
[info]  /Users/jacek/sandbox/so/andrey-workspace/sbt-demo-build
```

Comment: option 2: maybe I'm missing something but settings cannot be specified on a ProjectRef. since the existing project has a non-standard layout and uses a lot on un-managed dependencies there's quite a bit of configuration that needs to be done for module1 and module2 (like setting unmanagedSourceDirectories, unmanagedJars, etc.)

Comment: That's correct - I wrote *It assumes module1 and module2 are SBT projects*. I don't know if there's a better way. Looking into it and hoping others chime in in the meantime.

Comment: Hey, got it...perhaps. Since you're on Unix, what about symlinking it with `ln -s`? `module1` and `module2` could be symlinks to the real directories outside the SBT project.

Comment: yep, i thought of creating the soft links, but doing that seems like a hack. it would be good to know if there is a cleaner/supported way of doing this